# php - query selecting values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I must run a query selecting ID from the array `$id`...I've tried this but it doesn't work, I get this error: `"Notice: Array to string conversion"`...Why?

**Query**

```
$query6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album WHERE `id` 
IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $id)) . ')';'");
```

Comment: Put your array conversion on its own line. Making this a one-liner is unnecessary (and probably problematic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$query6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(',', 
array_map('intval', $id)) . ");");
```

Comment: it doesn't work! now I don't get error, but the query fails...
with if($query6)
  echo "ok!";
 else
  echo "error!"; it print error

Comment: did you try to run the query directly in mysql ? like in phpMyAdmin? or try to echo `mysqli_error()`

Comment: sorry, I unintentionally added a ', it works now!
Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you open your query string with a double quote ("), you'll need to close it the same way. Currently, you are closing it with a single quote (').

Try this:

```
$query6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM album 
        WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(',', array_map('intval', $id)) . ");");
```

Comment: you made a mistake too, try echoing your query

Comment: took my down vote back. but your answer is exactly the same as mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM album WHERE `id` IN(".implode(', ', array_map('intval', 
        $id)).");" ;

 $query6 = $mysqli->query( $sql );
```